# Laravel: Retrieving Data in Loop in a One to Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8. Here's my code...

CreateSchoolsTable migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

CreateStudentsTable migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('school_id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

School model

```
class School extends Model
{
    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
    }
}
```

Student Model

```
class Student extends Model
{
    public function school()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
class SchoolsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $schools = School::all();

        return view('schools.index', compact('schools'));
    }
}
```

My view: views>schools>index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($schools as $school)
    {{ $school->students->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

I want to display all the first names in the loop and `$school->students->first_name` gives me an error.

Property [first_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /Users/philginsburg/Laravel/project1/resources/views/schools/index.blade.php)

When I echo out `$school->students` it displays an array of the students table, but not sure why I cant loop through with the field name like `first_name`.

Comment: Another thing that is not said in the answers is that doing the query in that way, you will have a n +1 problem looping through the data. Instead of using `all()`, you can use eager loading to avoid it https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you are dealing with 2 Collections: `schools` and `students` (of each school), so you should use 2 different loop to loop through those collections, like this:

```php
@foreach ($schools as $school)
    <p>In this school there are those students:</p>
    <ul>
       @foreach($school->students as $student)
           <li>{{ $student->first_name }}</li>
       @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `$school->students` is array, there is no property called `first_name`.

you need to

```php
@foreach ($school->students as $student)
    {{ $student->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: it is a Collection, not an array